# How do I add to the first empty index in a generic type array?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am making an ArrayList class from scratch using generic types, and one of the methods I need to include is one that adds an element to the first empty index in the arrayList.

I initialized the array with `T[] list = (T[]) new Comparable[size];`

Say `size = 10;` and indices 0-3 are filled with various Objects. How would I locate index 4 as the first empty index? Are generic arrays initialized with nulls or something else?

Thank you

Comment: Normally you keep an index of the size of the list (size = number of elements stored in the list).  This is also the pointer to the first empty index.

Comment: @markspace that makes so much sense. Thank you

Comment: Just for the record, a generic array's elements would, indeed, be initialized to `null`s (as generic types are always reference types and arrays of reference types are always initialized to all `null`s). But @markspace points out, you might neither want nor need to make use of that fact...

Answer (score 0):

There are really 2 types of arrays in Java: Primitive arrays and object arrays. *Hint:* Generics are objects.

The elements of primitive arrays are initialized to `0`, or `false` for a `boolean[]`, and the elements of object arrays are initialized to `null`.

Those are the exact same default values that are also assigned to fields of the given types, e.g. a field like this will be `null` by default:

```
private Comparable<Foo> comparable;
```